# Discord.js: Error: "Cannot find module 'node:events'" after updating to v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Today I updated my node version from 12.x to 17.1.0 and my discord.js to 13.3.1. The process of updating was successful but after I run my bot, it outputs the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/rice-v13/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/rice-v13/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/runner/rice-v13/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/rice-v13/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19
```

Also, I noticed that when I installed a new node version via shell it outputs a warning:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

I surfed this question on the Internet and only found answers like "You gotta have node version 16 or higher" but I actually have 17.1.0.

Comment: This error shouldn't happen anywhere in v17.1.0

Comment: @MrMythical i updated the question, more details

Comment: It's not installing `fsevents` it says?

Comment: @MrMythical yeah, it is unsupported, how do i fix that

Comment: it says it wants your `os` to be `darwin` but it's `linux`. I don't know how to fix it, I've never gotten anything like this

Comment: @MrMythical sad

Comment: If you didn't notice, you put the error 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using replit for your bot.
This error happens when your repl node version is not high enough.
You can fix that by using the NodeJS v16 Template (https://replit.com/@RoBlockHead/NodeJS-16). Just fork that repl template and move all your code there.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Type:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question.